# Improving java file i/o performance when using a mapped network drive on Windows

Tags: java, windows, io

We've created a java application that (among other things) uses the built-in file IO libraries to access a list of files inside a particular folder on a network share.  When the folder is specified as a local file (e.g., c:\foobar), performance is fine.  However, if we map a network drive to the folder, *even if the folder is on the same machine* (e.g., z:\ -> c:\foobar), performance goes through the floor.  Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?  More importantly, any suggestions on how to improve the situation?

Comment: What might be causing the problem: SMB :-) Perhaps try to simply speed up the remote FS access (e.g. ask on the superuser stack) or using more buffering (BufferedReader, etc, or more manually). If the work is "background" you may also make the app "seem more responsive" by using some worker threads.

Comment: Are there a whole bunch of files in the directory?  The delay may come from windows sending a huge list of files through the protocol.

Comment: There may indeed be many files (thousands) in the directory.  What is it about the protocol that slows things down?  We don't have this issue on Linux or Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which version of windows you're using but it's well-acknowledged that early versions of SMB have [performance issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#Performance_issues). In a nutshell: later (e.g. Windows Server 2012) = better when it comes to performance, although you need to ensure that both the client and server are working on the latest version of SMB for maximum performance.